# Did Instagram change API rate limits on Mar 30, 2018?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I use some self developed script to get info about my posts and followers. Recently I discovered that Instagram changed rate limits for my app. I see following info in headers:

```
x-ratelimit-limit: 200
```

I learned Instagram blog and page with changes but found no mentions about any changes since Oct 1, 2017.

Is this new limit related only to my token or to entire platform? Could you check your token?

Comment: @NickFanilov seeing the same thing.  Used to be 5000 calls per hour per user of your app.  Now down to 200.  Have also found no documentation of change leading up to it.  The Instagram Platform API is scheduled for stages of deprecation, but not until later this year.

Comment: @NickFanilov I'm experiencing the same thing, Didn't see any information online but limits are reduced to 200 calls/h I wonder if that is a bug or if it is connected with recent FB privacy scandal and FB response

Comment: I also have the same issue since midnight. Suddenly limit is decreased without any notification. There is no info on Instagram website either

Comment: This is certainly a global change. Their limits should be mentioned here:
[https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/), but this link currently responds with 404. While official information is absent, it's a good reason to keep this question opened

Comment: They were one day too early with their API April Fools joke..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes It is, Although no official communication.
I also experienced that.
I found this in their documentation.

*The Instagram API uses the same rate limiting as the Graph API (200 calls per user per hour) with one exception: the /media/comments edge limits writes to 60 writes per user per hour. Please refer to the Graph API's rate limiting documentation for more information.*

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting

https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/
Hope this will be helpful.

Update:-

Further on 4th April few more APIs deprecated by Instagram.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

Answer (score 4):

Some perspective:

This 200 per hour call has been in the Graph API documentation for at least a month (according to wayback machine).

Facebook must have panicked over the weekend and pressed the "require Graph API permissions" button, thus our current situation. :\

Comment: Indeed, from my understanding Instagram API (soon deprecated) is different from Instagram API Graph which is aimed at businesses. Now, why in the world would I develop an app using Graph API given how the current API users have been treated

Comment: Good question! Sometimes I hope FB goes out of business so us poor code monkeys don't have to mess with it anymore :\

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

The limit has been reduced.

Here are some reference links for detailed documentation:

[Instagram API limit reduced to 200 from 5000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585077/instagram-api-limit-reduced-to-200-from-5000)

https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting

Hope it helps

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's our answer:  https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

The API deprecated immediately. So really the limits probably don't matter that much anymore. I really don't see myself building another app based on their API...

Comment: The old Instagram API was deprecated. But the Graph API includes Instagram endpoints.

Comment: only for business accounts at the moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499402/instagram-api-for-non-business-accounts @JoshuaDance

Answer (score 2):

Here is  The New Instagram's Public Api Update , unfortunately Limit rates are worthless for some Features in Instagram . 
   **April 4, 2018**

```
The following endpoints are deprecated immediately:
Follows and Relationships
GET /users/self/follows
GET /users/self/followed-by
GET /users/self/requested-by
GET /users/{user-id}/relationship
POST /users/{user-id}/relationship
Commenting on Public Content
GET /media/{media-id}/comments (Deprecation not relevant when fetching comments for self media)
POST /media/{media-id}/comments
DEL /media/{media-id}/comments/comment-id
Media
GET /media/{media-id}
GET /media/shortcode/{shortcode}
Likes
GET /media/{media-id}/likes
POST /media/{media-id}/likes
DEL /media/{media-id}/likes
User Search
GET /users/{user-id}
GET /users/{user-id}/media/recent
GET /users/self/media/liked
GET /users/search
Subscriptions - to receive notifications when media is posted
Some information on Public Content returned through hashtag and location search will be removed - Name, Bio, Comments, Commenters, Follower Count, Following Count, Post Count, and Profile Picture
```