# Instagram API limit reduced to 200 from 5000

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Does anyone have any clue why Instagram has reduced their hourly API request limit from 5000 to just 200? Is this a bug or the new normal? Do instagram partners undergo the same lowering of rate limit?

The page on rate limits in the documentation [is a broken link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/).

**:::UPDATES FROM INSTAGRAM via MAIL:::**

To summarize, Basically Instagram API is shutting down faster than speed of light right now. Migrate your apps to FB-instagram-API to keep your business or apps running

Comment: You're referring to a broken link!

Comment: That's the point. Its a broken link from the docs.

Comment: Same for me :(  Instagram API request failed, response http code is: '429', response
is: '{"error_type": "OAuthRateLimitException", "code": 429,
"error_message": "You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per
hour. You have performed a total of 426 requests in the last hour. Our
general maximum limit is set at 200 requests per hour."}'

Comment: Noticed this too ☹ maybe quick changes following the Cambridge Analytica scandal.

Comment: The link to limit doc has been broken for at least one month, I noticed that back then

Comment: Do you guys think this is a bug and will be resolved within a couple of hours or is this the new limit that they are allowing?

Comment: @NarayaN I think that, unfortunately, it's the new rate limit, the message is clear: "Our general maximum limit is set at 200 requests per hour"

But, as usual, they have not notified the users of the API before making the change and they have no added nothing to their API change log: https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

Comment: See this as well: https://www.facebook.com/events/1775403846100340/?ti=icl

Comment: @Ka. That content is not available. Could you please share what you saw before it got deleted or blocked?

Comment: Now, why in the world would I develop an app using Graph API given how the current API users have been treated

Comment: each page request of a paginated endpoint all counts as 1 request towards the rate limit right?

Comment: @Gukki5 If you use 1 API endpoint, It is counted as 1. So yes in your case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, from what I think are updated Facebook docs.

> Rate Limiting
>
> The Instagram API uses the same rate limiting as the Graph API (200 calls per user per hour) with one exception: the /media/comments edge limits writes to 60 writes per user per hour. Please refer to the Graph API's rate limiting documentation for more information.

[Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting)

Comment: Do instagram partners undergo the same lowering of rate limit ?

Answer (score 13):

Seems to be in relation to trying to clean up privacy and user data usage.

TechCrunch article - https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/

> Without warning, Instagram  has broken many of the unofficial apps
>   built on its platform. This weekend it surprised developers with a
>   massive reduction in how much data they can pull from the Instagram
>   API, shrinking the API limit from 5,000 to 200 calls per user per
>   hour. Apps that help people figure out if their followers follow them
>   back or interact with them, analyze their audiences or find relevant
>   hashtags are now quickly running into their API limits, leading to
>   broken functionality and pissed off users.
>
> Two sources confirmed the new limits to TechCrunch, and developers are
>   complaining about the situation on StackOverflow.

Comment: Seems they reverted... the error spike in our logs dropped...

Comment: Nevermind, they are back: `You have performed a total of 219 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum limit is set at 200 requests per hour`

Comment: As far as I understand, They will not revert back.

Comment: Limit now set to 500 it seems... `You have performed a total of 525 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum limit is set at 500 requests per hour`

Comment: @dstj I am not experiencing this, can you provide more information? I'm still seeing 200 request limit in headers

Comment: I experience limit set to 500 only in sandbox mode. In normal mode still 200.

Comment: Damn you put me into an infinite loop following the circular reference!