# How to report API Rate Limit issue to Instagram since developer Dashboard is not accessible?

Tags: instagram

The x-ratelimit-remaining response looks strange:

```
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 29
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 28
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 27
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 25
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 23
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 22
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 20
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 19
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 17
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 16
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 15
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 13
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 12
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 11
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 9
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 8
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 7
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 5
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 3
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 18
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 16
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 15
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 14
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 12
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 10
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 9
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 7
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 6
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 4
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 3
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 2
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 0
```

we cannot report this issue to the instagram support since the Developer Dashboard page is not accessible, so how do we report?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using 2 tokens in the round-robin way, It's reflecting the remaining request for each of token.

You may be facing this because Instagram recently changed rate limit.
More details here.
[Did Instagram change API rate limits on Mar 30, 2018?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583489/did-instagram-change-api-rate-limits-on-mar-30-2018)