# Instagram API for Non-Business accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I want to make a app for Non-Bussiness Instagram accounts.
My only problem is that when I access the old Instagram API (https://www.instagram.com/developer/) they tell me to use the new Graph API, but when I go to the Instagram Graph API reference, they says:

> If you are building apps for Instagram Non-Business Accounts, please
>   use the Instagram Platform API instead.

(Note: The old Instagram API will be deprecated soon: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/) 
What can I do to resolve this little problem?

Comment: Quote from the blog post you linked to: _“Future updates on the Instagram Graph API will include: Support for Non-Business Profiles [FUTURE]: Basic permissioning for non-business profiles will be supported in early 2019.”_ Might simply mean that you can not interact with non-business Instagram accounts via any API in the meantime.

Comment: @CBroe I really don't read all text (my bad). Thanks for your reply

Comment: well, its 2020 now, still cannot get some data for non-business profiles, such as followers_count

Answer (score 0):

Instagram users can now set their accounts as 'creator accounts'. This allows the same capabilities via the Facebook Graph API as for business accounts, but without actually needing to be a business.

Details here: https://help.instagram.com/2358103564437429