# Instagram API obtaining users information from those that engages

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

If I have a following on Instagram that engages with my content, and also has an online presence that has signed up users, is there a way to connect the two?

Is there a way to find out if a user on Instagram likes a photo, and see if that user has signed up on my website?

I wasn't able to find an API endpoint that can get users ID that likes or comments Instagram photos, or even does an action on Instagram stories (watching/swiping up/etc).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like a change in April of this year deprecated a lot of Instagram endpoints: https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/ - `GET /media/{media-id}/likes` seems like an endpoint you would have found useful, as well as `GET /media/{media-id}/comments` (the 2nd is deprecated for non-self media).

See also: [Did Instagram change API rate limits on Mar 30, 2018?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583489/did-instagram-change-api-rate-limits-on-mar-30-2018)